# Array Aggregator function for Django using Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to use `array_agg()` function of `postgresql` in `django 1.8`, but could not bump into a solution as of now. What I have come across is [this](http://ivan-klass.blogspot.in/2013/02/postgresql-arrayagg-function-in-django.html). But the function is broken. Also no luck with using `raw query`, because we need to always include the `primary key` of the table and the field I want to use `array_agg()` is not the primary key. I am stuck. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function has been added in `django-dev`.You can find it [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/postgres/aggregates/general.py).

```
class ArrayAgg(Aggregate):
    function = 'ARRAY_AGG'

    def convert_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        if not value:
            return []
        return value
```

For now you can add ^ as custom class.